# Repeating notification sound

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Is it possible (and if yes how) to make push notification sound repeat until it's read? I am creating app that notifies user about new event in app, but user needs to read notification as soon as possible. When user "reads" notification it should stop ringing. Here's code:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
String mes;
HelperGlobals glob;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}


@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    glob = (HelperGlobals) getApplicationContext();

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    // .... Doing work here

    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

}


public void createPush(String title, String msg, Intent intent) {

    Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://example.project.com/" + R.raw.notification);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DoNothing.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build(); 
    n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    //n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
    n.sound = soundUri;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, n); 
}

}
```

And BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("BukuLog", "Receiver");
    // Explicitly specify that GcmMessageHandler will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMIntentService.class.getName());

    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**int FLAG_INSISTENT** :  Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that if set, the audio will be repeated until the notification is cancelled or the notification window is opened.

follow [android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)

Comment: FLAG_INSISTENT is not working on Oreo above.can you please suggest something?

Comment: Generally it helps. But if there is an active GSM call, my notification sound is replaced with a single beep. The problem is that this beep is not repeating even if FLAG_INSISTENT is set. Any ideas how to make it repeating as well?

Answer (score 22):

like this:

```
        Notification note = mBuilder.build();
        //here
        note.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, note);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.