# Android: How do I repeat a notification sound until the notification is opened?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-handler

I am currently working on an Android App, that needs to alarm the user in case of an emergency. When the app needs to alert, it notifies the user with a heads-up notification and plays a loud sound. My problem is that I can't get the sound to repeat itself after it ends. I basically want it to loop until the users opens the notification.

I've tried to use `Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT` in both `notification.flags` and `audioAttributes.setFlags(...)` (inside of `notificationChannel.setSound(audio, audioAttributes)`), however this doesn't work.

Thanks ^^

Comment: do you have code that can play the notification sound outside of a notification? If you achieve this then you could use the notification to set a flag that triggers this repeated code to play the sound over and over, then when the notification is read, the flag is unset. You may need some sort of service to make this happen outside of the application context.

Comment: @Chris thanks! I have a method that can handle the notification sound, I use it to make sounds in case of a full screen intent. Unfortunately I don't know how to use Flags, how do I trigger it?

Comment: Hey, I had similar issue but I got it resolved with setting `Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT` on a `notification.flags`. Perhaps you could share a code snippet showing how you do it. I found [Repeating notification sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461523/repeating-notification-sound) SO question which helped me to get my solution working.

Answer (score 0):

I check in DeskClock app in AOSP, they set sound of notification to null then use MediaPlayer to play sound.

```
channel.setSound(null, null)
```

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock/NotificationUtils.kt